# Prevent divs from moving over one another

Tags: html, css

I have my contact page with three icons that are placed horizontally next to one another. The problem comes in when you resize the browser to about phone size (480px around so) the divs start to flow over one another and the images stack on top and is really not something I want to happen. I want them to either go below one another or scale accordingly.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Home</title>
        <!--===================================================css links===================================================!-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/default_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/contact_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>   
    <body>
        <!--===================================================Header===================================================!-->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="headerwrap">
                <div class="social">    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
 <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>
                </div>
                <!--close social!-->
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" />
                    </div>
                    <!--close logo-->
                </div>
                <!--close header!-->
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul class="menutxt">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="manga.html">CONTACT</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--close menu!-->
            </div>
            <!--close headerwrap!-->
            <!--===================================================Contact===================================================!-->
            <div class="toptxt">
                <div id="test2">
                    <p class="menutxt">Get in touch...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detailwrap">
                <div class="contactspace"></div>
                <!--close contactspace!-->
                <div class="contact">
                    <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/me2.png">
                    <p class="text">Luke Babich</p>
                </div>
                <!--close contact!-->
                <div class="contact">
                    <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/phone.png">
                    <p class="text">+27 72 836 0954</p>
                </div>
                <!--close contact!-->
                <div class="contact">
                    <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/mail.png">
                    <p class="text">lukerbab@gmail.com</p>
                </div>
                <!--close contact!-->
                <div class="contactspace"></div>
                <!--close contactspace!-->
            </div>
            <!--close detailwrap!-->
            <!--===================================================Footer===================================================!-->
            <div class="footerwrap2">
                <p class="foottxt">Designed and developed by Luke Babich- All Rights Reserved ©2015</p>
            </div>
            <!--close footerwrap!-->
        </div>
        <!--close wrapper!-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
.toptxt{
    margin-top:70px;
    width:100%;
}
/*.contactwrap{
    width:100%;                 change back if cant figure it out
    margin-top:60px;
}*/ 
.detailwrap{
    top:70px; /*remove if needed*/
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
/* clearfix */
.detailwrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.contact{
    position:relative;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 2% 0;
}
.contactspace{
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;   
}
.contact img{
    width:90px;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.contact .text {
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
    text-align:center;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.contact:hover .text {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    visibility:visible;
}
img.move2 {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move2:hover {
    -moz-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -o-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    transform: translate(0px, -10px)    
}
/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
.contentwrap{   
    margin-top:500px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:500;
    background:#171717;
}
.textwrap{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px #000;
}
/* clearfix */
.textwrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.content,
.divider,
.content2,
.contentspace {
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}
.divider{
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.divider img{
    display: block;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.content,
.content2 {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.content img{
    width:15%;
}
.contentspace{
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;   
}
.headertxt{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:1.5vw;
}
/*---------------------------- Footer ----------------------------*/
.footerwrap2{
    position:relative;
    top:70px; /*remove if needed*/
    width:100%;
    z-index:501;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px #000;
}
/*---------------------------- Textfader ----------------------------*/
#test2 p {
    animation: fadein 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 5s; /* Opera */
    transition: opacity 5s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the problem comes in that my divs are all the same class.contact (not sure if that should affect the position of the overflowing divs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the .contactspace all together and instead center the .contact and add a min-width.

```
.detailwrap{
    top:70px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center; /* center align .contacts */
}

.contact {
    display: inline-block; /* make it possible to use text-align */
    position:relative;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 115px; /* avoid 15% being making the contacts less than 115px */
    margin: 0 1% 2% 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hf04x562/

Comment: will give that a go. Only reason i used that was took it from my previous page which needed a good image spacer.

Comment: all right that seems to solve the problem. Only thing thats wrong that at about 780px when changing the browser the images go out of line.

Comment: Out of line in what way? I just tried and the only point they go out of line in my experience is at really low resolutions (sub 350px).

Comment: I solved the issue by increasing .contact min-width to a larger amount and that seems to make them stack a bit earlier and not go out of line. Basically what it did was that at about 780px the middle image would be a little lower than the other two next to it and then they would eventually stack at around 350px.

Comment: No you solved the problem in both ways. I needed it to scale in a certain way, and just changed the code a bit to suit my other style sheet I have with the one I linked here. So thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You should try using 
`display: block; float: left; margin: auto`
 Reason being is that you're positioning needlessly in my opinion, and the way you position (relatively) is causing things to be pushed when you don't want them to because it positions relative to it's current position, which isn't very responsive unless you make it so.

Comment: which div are you referring to specifically?